# When printing an Infopath form in Sharepoint, page breaks do not translate

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, infopath, custom-form, printing

I have a sharepoint list with modified views from Infopath. In Infopath, I inserted page breaks. However, when I try to print a list item, the page breaks do not translate.

I just get a bunch of lines cut off from page to page. The page breaks work when printing from Infopath. It does not work when printing from sharepoint on ie or chrome.

Can anyone think of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use InfoPath Form viewer web part on a Page, call it PrintPage.aspx to display your infopath form print view. And then use print page option. It should print fine.

Comment: The problem with this is that I can't view specific list items.

Comment: Yes you can. Put two webparts on your page. One for your list and other for you InfoPath Form. Connect these webparts and your form display webpart should get the "form data" from your list web part. Each item you will select from the list webpart it will display the associated form on the form web part.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't see how you can receive all "form data" through a web part connection.  I can send one row field, but not all row fields. Even if this is possible, I don't understand this "print page option" that you mentioned.

Comment: Try re reading my previous two comments you will get an idea. Create a page first. Add two web parts, one for list other to display your form. once these webparts are connected, you will select a list item and the respective form will be displayed on the other web part. you have to create a print view in the form and display all the data/fields you want to display on that view.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand the previous two comments. But I don't know how you are connecting every field. When I make a connection it ONLY connect 1 field. How do I connect every single field? And after this is accomplished. I don't see how it will be printed with my desired page breaks. I do have a print view. Now when I print, I have another web part that is trying to get printed.

Comment: You just connect with 1 field and it should load your form. Example: Form ID or any other unique field which should let you access the form. Load the Print view and then try to print using Print Page option.

Comment: I believe you just keep telling me to do same thing over and over again. I have done exactly what you recommend and the problem is that it does not load the complete form. On top of this, I don't believe your print solution answers my original question.